# How can I tell whether the current working directory is ignored by Git?

Tags: git, bash, directory, gitignore

I have a git controlled directory (actually my home directory) within which there are ignored directories (e.g. trash space, and directories controlled by other VCSs).  I want to be able to have my bash prompt show whether a directory is version controlled and if so by which VCS, but e.g. `git rev-parse` will always find the topmost `.git` directory.

Is there a way to ask git whether I'm in an untracked directory?

I've found this to work:

```
if ! git rev-parse 2>&/dev/null; then
    echo "not in git"
else
    PREFIX=$(git rev-parse --show-prefix)
    if [ -z "$PREFIX" ]; then
        echo "at git top level"
    elif [ -z $(cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel); \
          git ls-files -o --directory "${PREFIX%%/}")
        echo "tracked by git"
    else
        echo "untracked"
    fi
fi
```

However it seems very hackish and brittle.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Git doesn't track directories. It only tracks files.

Comment: True, but I can tell it to ignore directories in `.gitignore`, so it has some knowledge of them.

Comment: Ignoring a directory in .gitignore really just ignores all files in the directory (with the side-effect of not even recursing into the directory to check for negated patterns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git clean -nd` approach: If it is ignored directory, then `git clean -d` wants to remove it, so it is easy way to check status of current directory.

```
if git clean -xnd `pwd` | grep 'Would remove \./' > /dev/null; then
    echo "Inside ignored or untracked directory"
else
    echo "Inside normal directory"
fi
```

Tweak `git clean` to change rules about untracked files. Checked in my $HOME repository.

Note: don't experiment with `git clean` without `-n` lightly, it can clear things from your home.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  It's still a little confusing (why do I have to use `pwd` instead of just `.`?) but much clearer than what I had.

Answer (score 2):

For the question of *ignored* folders specifically, you can use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) and test the error code.

```
$ cd ~/project
$ git check-ignore tracked-folder
$ echo $?
1
$ git check-ignore ignored-folder
ignored-folder
$ echo $?
0
```

Untracked folders appear to have the same behavior as tracked (but not ignored) folders. Adding a `-v` will show you which rules make the folder (or file) ignored.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [bash_completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) and a modified **PROMPT_COMMAND**. It worked for me in casual testing, but if it breaks you own both pieces. :)

```
# Add this to your shell startup file (e.g. ~/.bashrc).
export PS1
export PROMPT_COMMAND='
    if fgrep -q "${PWD/\/home\/$LOGNAME\/}" ~/.gitignore; then
        PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1) [ignored]\$ "
    else
        PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(__git_ps1)\$ "
    fi'
```

To make this work, you'll need to make sure all your ignored paths are listed relative to your home directory, and be sure to test it out before relying on it to protect you from any destructive operations like `rm -rf`.

Comment: Doesn't handle: 1. per-directory .gitignores, 2. global gitignore file, 3. .git/info/exclude, 4. "!exclusion" patters.